# Why didn't Harkness ever question why he doesn't look or sound like himself anymore?

Tags: fallout

In *Fallout 3,* Dr. Pinkerton changed  A3-21's face and voice, but he didn't bother to find out how Harkness was supposed to sound or look, he just obtained a memory and put him into the android. Why didn't Harkness ever question his own face or voice?

Answer (score 2):

According to logs on Pinkerton's terminal A3-21 woke from the surgery confused, however the 'mem chip' that Pinkerton put into him and the cover story about being in a coma seemed to be enough to get him to accept he was a combat veteran named 'Harkness'. Fallout 4 expanded the information about how android/synth memories are altered via a full memory wipe, and this wipe presumably includes wiping memories of their original voice and face.

From the Fallout wiki [here](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Rivet_City_terminal_entries#Android_log_2):

> I stole the mem chip from that jerk Braun... Of course, I won't know whose memories are on this thing until I integrate it into it's [sic] new host. But they never specified, so it shouldn't really matter. I can't wait until the subject arrives.

> I got those memories into that Android like I was God sending down messages from Heaven. **Calls himself "Harkness" now. Thinks he's an old combat veteran.** Did a little extra tinkering with his reflex system. He's certainly not someone I'd want to meet in a fight. **When he "woke up" he was all confused. We told him he was in a coma for a long time.** Between the new memories and the new face I gave him, there isn't anyone that would recognize him. Not even himself!

These [mem chips](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Mem_chip) are apparently only mentioned in Fallout 3, however in Fallout 4 the fact that synths can get new faces, voices, and memories is a key plot point. According to [a holotape from H2-22](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Goodbye_from_H2-22), there is an optional procedure that synths can undergo to lose *all* of their memories in order to start a completely new life:

> The doctor said I could say goodbye. I've decided... to have the operation. **I know I'll lose all my memories.** I don't want you to be sad. I... I have nightmares. And this world, the SRB, being hunted. I just can't handle it. Everyone says I'll be safer if I start a new life. I know I'll be happier...